# wordpress pretty urls redirects to home page

Tags: wordpress

after changing site domain name, WordPress pretty URL's redirects to home page. If I change the permalink to default it works fine. But with pretty URLS's half my links redirect to the homepage.

I have tried:

- checking for redirects in .htaccess
- disabling all plugins
- checking the database for redirects (can't find any in the options table, they might still be there though)
- changing the permalink to default and back again to no result.
- When they redirect the go through a 404 not found.

does anyone have a suggestion? I am getting desperate :)

Comment: ps: worked fine before the domain change.

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem of rewrite rules.

First try to change permalink to default and then refresh page. See if it works. If it works then change permalink back to your previous assigned one and then check again if it works.

If above helps you then its ok. Otherwise try to use Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

Comment: Your right I was a nit wit, tested it now however and flushed the rewrites to no effect. :/

Comment: please check permission of .htaccess file it should be writable

Comment: I have manually overwritten the .htaccess file with the default wordpress file. there are no rewriting going on there.. so that won't help :)